# Google Calendar Resources iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-objc-client

I´m using the [google-api-objectivec-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) for iOS to get the list of Calendars.

While I can see the calendars for resources (like rooms, etc..), I see other kind of calendars, such as the **personal** calendar of the user, or the **"National holidays"** calendar or **"birthdays"** calendar. Thus needing to filter out these calendars that aren´t resources.

I´ve found this [Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/) which returns the list of the specific calendars for resources only, using `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/MYDOMAIN.com/` as a regular HTTP GET call using AFNetworking instead of Google´s SDK.

But I haven´t found a way to retrieve just the specific calendars for resources using `GTLQueryCalendar` nor a specific class for Calendar Resources.

Is there other class in the sdk or maybe another sdk that I could use for this purpose? How could I use it?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope. We didn't continue digging it. And I didn't find any API in the SDK to do it

Comment: I found below API which gives me calendar resources:  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with the `GTLQueryCalendar`. Here is how:

This will retrieve a list of upcoming events from the specify `calendarID`

```
GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsListWithCalendarId:@"calendarId"];
}
```

You can find the complete example from the [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios). 
Good luck!

Comment: What I need is to get the list of `Calendar Resources`... This way I´d be retrieving upcoming events for a given `CalendarId`; The equivalent to `GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/{domain name}/`

Comment: This is unclear to me- you mentioned that you can see the calendar resources and other kinds of calendars, but you still need to get list of Calendar Resources. Can you provide some use case and maybe some examples or calls to API you're making?

Comment: I´ve updated my question with a more detailed explanation to see if you can understand me better now. With the whole list of calendars I don´t know how to know which ones are resources and which aren´t, by any other mean that filtering by known names, which doesn´t seem the most reliable way to do this